# Почему-то работает не так как должно

Tags: c++

Есть у меня код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, " ");
    int x,y,sum1,sum2;
    sum1 = sum2 = 0;
    for (; ; ) {
        cout << "Введите номер своего билета" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        y = (x == 0 ? 1 : int(log10(x) + 1));
        if (y != 6) cout << "Номер билета имеет 6 цифер, и не начинається числом '0'. Повторите попитку." << endl;
        if ((y == 6) and (y % 100000 != 0)) break;
    }
    cout << "Всё введено верно." << endl;
    sum1 += (x % 10) + (x % 1000) + (x % 100000);
    sum2 += (x % 100) + (x % 10000) + (x % 1000000);
    if (sum1 == sum2)cout << "Удачний билет." << endl;
    else cout << "Ваш удачний билет в наступном тролейбусе" << endl;
    cout << sum1 << "_" << sum2 << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Должно выводить "Удачный билет." когда сумма цифр которые стоят на непарных местах равна суме цифр стоящих на парных местах
(по типу 3+6+5 = 7+4+3).
Ввел 295163, и мне вывело:

```
Все введено верно
Ваш удачный билет в следующем троллейбусе.
95329_300389
```

Я ожидал на:

```
Все введено верно  
Удачний билет. ‭ 
13‬_‭13‬
```

Почему оно додаётся как текст, а не как числа? И как это исправить?

Comment: Так, стоп. Что вам в моём вопросе не понравилось? Ну я следовал структуре: мой код; результат; ожидаемой результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмите листок бумаги и карандаш и проверьте, что Вы вычисляете.

Вот это

```
(x % 1000)
```

не третья цифра справа. А вот это

```
(х / 100) % 10
```

или вот это

```
(x % 1000 - x % 100) / 100
```

третья цифра справа.

---

```
sum1 = (x % 10) + ((х / 100) % 10) + ...
```

Comment: а еще я думал, что счастливый билет это типо 901505 xD

Comment: @Andrey "Что такое счастье, каждый понимал по-своему ..." А.Гайдар "Чук и Гек"